# Remove $$Units from the table below

Tags: python, replace

I have garbage values($$ Units) in the column B.
I am trying the following code but it is not changing anything.

```
s1.number_of_contents_in_sales_package.replace("$$Units", ' ',regex = True)
```

The table is as below

```
Column_A     number_of_contents_in_sales_package
0                  42
1          112$$Units
2           96$$Units
3           56$$Units
4           76$$Units
5           78$$Units
6           78$$Units
```

Comment: what is s1 and number_of_contents_in_sales_package here?

Comment: s1 is df name and 'number_of_contents_in_sales_package' is column b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` as below:

```
s1['number_of_contents_in_sales_package'] = s1['number_of_contents_in_sales_package'].apply(lambda x : str(x).replace("$$Units",""))
```

Comment: I am getting this error AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 1):

Hope below code will help you

```
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('$$unit', ''))
```

Comment: I am getting the error <br/>AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: replace method only works with the string, so you need to type cast to string like str(x).replace()